# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate debugger not showing entire list

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, f#

I have placed a breakpoint in my F# code to examine the contents of a particular list.  The count at the top clearly says that the list contains 93 elements, something I have confirmed separately in SQL.  But the debugger gets truncated after the 51st element, as can be seen from the snippet below:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I cannot see the entire list?  I don't remember encountering this error before.  Do I need to set some configuration variable somewhere?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can also observe this behavior in VS 2013 Pro update 2.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki Thank you for confirming that.  So, it is likely a bug in Visual Studio, and needs to be filed as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is baked into the runtime, and was evidently a deliberate design decision at some point. See the relevant line in [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3284)

Not sure why this limit was imposed. You can file a bug on the [Codeplex page](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) if you want to see this changed.

Comment: Now, `that` is a definitive answer.  Thank you very much.